# My brother was shocked plugging in an HDMI cable, what could be the cause?

Tags: electrical

Recently--like last week--we got Direct TV installed in our home on a Tuesday.  On that Thursday my brother went to plug an HDMI cable into the TV so that he could play the PS3. There was a big ball of orange light, a bang sound, and his fingers received burns. The TV and game system were in use for three months prior to the installation of the Direct TV equipment.  What would have caused the jolt to come out of the TV from plugging in an HDMI cable? Not only did it burn my brother, but we believe it fried the TV as well.

Comment: *Electrocution* is **death** by electric shock. I am sorry to hear your brother was injured, but he was not "electrocuted", he was shocked.

Comment: Is could have been a static electrical discharge. The Direct TV installer(s) should have grounded the coax cables from the satellite dish, and the equipment should be plugged into a grounded outlet so that everything is at the same voltage potential. Whatever the satellite installers grounded the coax cable to should also be electrically bonded to the grounding bus in your service panel.

Comment: Is the receptacle where the equipment is plugged in grounded? And I don't just mean does it have three prongs, I mean is the receptacle actually connected to the grounding system. Does the TV, have a 3 prong cord?  Did the cable installer ground the dish?  There should either be a grounding wire running down from the dish, or the coaxial cable coming from the dish should have a grounding conductor built in to it.  That grounding conductor should be connected to the grounding system.

Comment: You're probably going to have to have an electrician (or somebody with the knowledge and tools) troubleshoot this problem. This is a difficult problem to solve through the internet.

Comment: Right, so does this DirecTV come with a box that sits near the TV like a cable box? Does it need to be plugged into AC power?  How exactly was it plugged in?  Point is, most of the time when I'm trying to add a box, I have to move stuff around to make it fit.   Good chance doing so uncovered a serious flaw in your wiring or your extension cords.

Comment: Wondering if he was jamming the HDMI cable into the wrong socket.

Comment: @Craig It's absolutely impossible to have that size static charge.  Shorting a fully charged cap could have done it, but not surface charge.

Comment: Carl, **lightning** is a static discharge. Static charge buildup on *plastic* pipe is a big enough deal that [OSHA addresses it specifically](https://www.osha.gov/dts/hib/hib_data/hib19880930.html). I wasn't saying that was the cause, just one possible cause or contributor. Certainly a fully charged capacitor could do it--depending on the size of the capacitor. And since we're talking about HDMI cables here, I seriously doubt that we're talking about a CRT TV with a big capacitor on the back of the tube. I could also have been a direct short inside the PS3 or the TV, but how likely is that?

Comment: I also specifically asked about grounding. If the various parts of the system (coax antenna wire, electrical supply to the TV and PS3) aren't at the same voltage potential, this could easily happen. It's conceivable that there's a short somewhere in the electrical system in the house putting voltage on a ground somewhere, and that whatever the antenna cable is grounded to (if anything) isn't bonded to the house ground. Lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

If he received burns, it doesn't sound like static electricity. Another common source of sparks is the so called Y-filtering capacitors in ungrounded power supplies, but I've never heard of them causing burns, just a mild tingle.

It sounds more like he ended up shorting mains phase to ground or neutral. Which would most likely mean that one of your safety ground wires is actually connected to mains power, **an installation mistake that is very dangerous**. I suggest you get an electrician to check it out as soon as possible, and avoid touching the equipment in the meanwhile.